# Transferring data from Lotus Notes to DB2 using Agent

Tags: db2, lotus-notes

before you say something, I searched a lot but didn't find how to do that.

So I got database in .NSF format for use in Lotus Notes. I need to write an Agent (I know how to) so data from that database will be automatically transferred to DB2 database.

So before I create DB2 tables, how do i know which structure I need to use? How do I check how  exactly data in that .NSF file is stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notes documents are unstructured, there's no guarantee that any two documents in a database have the same structure. *You* will need to decide *what data* you want to transfer to a relational table, then check each document to see if it contains the corresponding fields (items). You didn't mention what language you're planning to use for your agent; in Java you would use `NotesDocument.getItems()` to enumerate all items in a document.

Comment: Thanks mustaccio! I'll be using LotusScript. I still haven't figured how do I see all the data in that NSF file, so I can decide what data to put where.

Answer (score 0):

As mustaccio also said, since Notes/Domino is a NoSQL database, you don't have a schema.
You should talk to the developer of the application and get an understanding of what data is lovated where.
You could of course use the Design Synopsis function in Domino Designer to export the actual design, but document can potentially contain data not showing up in the design.

If you want to export the documents as XML, I have a tool I wrote available here: http://www.texasswede.com/home.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter
You can export all the documents and then look at the XML to see what data you have.